# How to resolve error in running KModes algorithm in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a segmentation problem and I have a dataframe with 49 variables and 500000 observations which could be continous, binary or categorical. I'm reading only those variables which do not have any NA values in them. Also to be on the safe side I was also using na.omit option.

Now as the dataset is too large, I wass trying to incrementally run it and did a sample at 1000, 10000 and 50000 rows. It run successfully on 1000 and 10000 rows with the following code :

```
t1c <- t1[sample(nrow(t1),50000),-c(5,23,25,26,28,55)]
library(klaR)
segments <- kmodes(na.omit(t1c),4, iter.max = 5)
```

where t1 is my original dataframe. When I run this with 50000 rows, I got the following error

```
Error in match.arg(useNA) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

Any idea as to what might be the issue here.

P.s. Also I'm trying to run PAM using daisy() as it might be a better fit as I'm researching more on this for the type of data I have but still I was wondering if kmodes was running with 10000 samples, what might be an issue with 50000

Comment: Daisy (and PAM) will require O(n²) memory. Compute the memory requirements for n=500000...